# Sitecore display item title $name

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have an issue with Sitecore 7.1
In the homepage it display an item 2 times, one have title "$name" and one with the true title. (only one item but it appears 2 time)
This issue occurs on the staging enviroment and I dont' know how to get to this issue on my local machine. 
Any body suffered this issue?

Comment: Check if there is any Sitecore query that selects items by `@@templateId`.  It could get the ___Standard Values_ item alongside with the _content_ one (since the template is the same).

Answer (score 1):

**$name** is a token that can be placed in fields in Sitecore on **Standard Values** items to instruct Sitecore, upon creation of an item, to set the value of the field to be the name as the name of the item.  Here are two reasons you are seeing this on the front-end:

1. As @SergeyShushlyapin mentioned in his comment above, you may have code that is retrieving the **Standard Values** item itself
2. You may have code that is retrieving **all versions** of the item and is now picking up an old version of this item that still has the token in the field (the token may have been added to the **Standard Values** of this item's template **after** some versions of the item were created)

Answer (score 0):

In the Sitecore content editor,

- Go to the homepage item.
- Press "Presentation" tab in the top menu.
- Press "Details" button in Layout section top submenu

Now you see al placed controls on this page. Click edit and choice controls and delete the unwanted control, or fix the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue, where the content was displaying $name. The root cause of the issue is mentioned below:

1. The item does not have a version.
2. Template is version in other language.
3. Invariant Language is present in the Language list.